# How to debug go code on remote machine using Goland?

Tags: go, remote-debugging, goland

I have a go codebase on a remote machine that I'd like to be able to debug using Goland. I've been trying to figure out how to set something akin to PyCharm's remote interpreter, but I haven't been able to figure it out. The best I can find is their [blog's tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2019/02/06/debugging-with-goland-getting-started/), but it's complicated by docker containers and web applications. How do I set up Goland to remotely debug?

Comment: The blog is useful for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In that blog post, Docker containers are used to simulate a remote machine.

GoLand doesn't have anything similar to PyCharm's remote debugging at the moment.

The best thing you can do is to run your application using delve as it's shown in the example container in the blog post and then connect the IDE to the remote delve instance.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying :)

Comment: Can you explain why that is? What differences between Go and Python make creating remote debugging capabilities more difficult in Go?

Comment: At the moment, we simply don't have the implementation ready for this use-case. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-3322 for more details and feel free to add your use-case there.

Comment: I hope `goland` will have features called `remote development over ssh(wsl, docker)` like `vscode` `remote development extension`.

Comment: @toffee do you have an idea if this feature got introduced in goland

Comment: This feature is not the yet in GoLand, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-3322

Comment: This issue is tracking 'remote development support' for IntelliJ and includes GoLand in the proposal: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-226455. It currently has 492 votes, so worth adding your votes there.